# Swapping Columns of 2D List

Tags: python, list, 2d, swap

With a 2d list such as:

```
[['G', 'Y', 'V', 'X'], ['C', 'F', 'Z', 'Y'], ['B', 'X', 'B', 'J'], ['P', 'T', 'U', 'W']]
```

Is there a BIF/shorthand that would allow swapping, like the example below where each 0th index of each inner lists have been swapped with the 2nd index of the inner lists:

```
[['V', 'Y', 'G', 'X'], ['Z', 'F', 'C', 'Y'], ['B', 'X', 'B', 'J'], ['U', 'T', 'P', 'W']]
```

I have produced an iterative solution which works fine. But it would be nice to know if a BIF does exist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to just be reversing, are you swapping  or actually reversing all the elements? I think adding an example with more than three elements per sublist would be a better idea

Comment: be more clear: do you want reversal, swapping, or rotation?

Comment: As put in the OQ "Swapping". I can see why some have thought it could be reversed. I will be make an edit now for clarity

Comment: If you want this do happen inplace a loop is exactly what you should use, you could do it in one line but it would be less efficient, as it is all you need is two lines a for loop and `sub[0],sub[2] = sub[2],sub[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the swapping in place (which I assume), I'd to it like this:

```
def swap_in(lst, fro, to):
    lst[fro], lst[to] = lst[to], lst[fro]

lst = [['G', 'Y', 'V', 'X'], ['C', 'F', 'Z', 'Y'], ['B', 'X', 'B', 'J'], ['P', 'T', 'U', 'W']]

for sublist in lst:
    swap_in(sublist, 0, 2)

print(lst) # [['V', 'Y', 'G', 'X'], ['Z', 'F', 'C', 'Y'], ['B', 'X', 'B', 'J'], ['U', 'T', 'P', 'W']]
```

I don't know of any neat oneliner that is readable and does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is no, there is no efficient oneliner that will swap elements inplace like using a for loop and `sub[0],sub[2] = sub[2],sub[0]`, if you want a oneliner and to change the original list you would have to slice:

```
l = [['G', 'Y', 'V', 'X'], ['C', 'F', 'Z', 'Y'], ['B', 'X', 'B', 'J'], ['P', 'T', 'U', 'W']]

l[:] = [sub[2:3] + sub[1:2] + sub[0:1] + sub[3:] for sub in l]
```

which would be considerably less efficient as you are creating multiple new lists by slicing as opposed to simply swapping two references in a list.

If you passed the new order explicitly you could use `itemgetter` but that would also involve mapping to lists after.

```
l = [['G', 'Y', 'V', 'X'], ['C', 'F', 'Z', 'Y'], ['B', 'X', 'B', 'J'], ['P', 'T', 'U', 'W']]
from operator import itemgetter

l[:] = map(itemgetter(2, 1, 0, 3), l)

print(l)
```